# Applying scipy filter to multidimensional data

Tags: numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I have stereo audio data represented by a numpy array with a shape of `(2500, 2)`.  I'd like to filter it using scipy's `signal.sosflt()` function, but I'm getting:

```
ValueError: Invalid zi shape. With axis=0, an input with shape (2500, 2), and an sos array with 2 sections, zi must have shape (2, 2, 2), got (2, 2).
```

The only complexity in the code is that I'm initializing zi once when processing the first buffer, then using it to condition the filter on subsequent calls:

```
from scipy import signal

def setup():
    zi = None
    # define a narrow band filter centered around 440 Hz.
    sos = signal.butter(2, [438, 442], btype='bandpass', output='sos', fs=48000)

def process(src, dst):
    # src and dst shape = (2500, 0)
    if zi is None:
        zi = signal.sosfilt_zi(sos)  # initialize zi on first buffer
    dst, zi = signal.sosfilt(sos, src, axis=0, zi=zi)
```

(Note: I've tried `axis=-1` and `axis=1` but neither of those are correct.)

Answer (score 1):

A solution, but perhaps not the cleanest:

Since the source data is stereo, `sosfilt` needs two copies of `zi`, one for each channel.  The following will work, but *only* if `src` has two columns:

```
from scipy import signal

def setup():
    zi = None
    # define a narrow band filter centered around 440 Hz.
    sos = signal.butter(2, [438, 442], btype='bandpass', output='sos', fs=48000)

def process(src, dst):
    # src and dst shape = (2500, 0)
    if zi is None:
        tmp = signal.sosfilt_zi(sos)
        zi = [tmp, tmp]               # assumes source data has two columns
    dst, zi = signal.sosfilt(sos, src, axis=0, zi=zi)
```

This works, but a more general solution would initialize `zi` based on the shape of the source data.